# How to schedule a stored procedure in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures, mysql-routines

I have this stored procedure. How can I run this for example with intervals of 5 seconds? Like a routine for eliminate data with a time-stamp older than one day?

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `delete_rows_links` 
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE delete_rows_links
BEGIN 

    DELETE activation_link
    FROM activation_link_password_reset
    WHERE  TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, `time`, NOW()) < 1 ; 

END 

GO
```

Comment: Do you really need to run it **each 5 second**?

Comment: nop, with interval of 6 hours is fine. But to test is more easy with seconds :)

Comment: Running anything automatically every 5 seconds is probably a really bad idea.  Try running it once a day, or once an hour, so you don't completely kill your performance.

Comment: I also wouldn't bother re-creating the stored procedure every time you run it.  Then again, I wouldn't even bother with a stored procedure. It's a simple DELETE statement... just execute it using whichever scheduling method you prefer.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

You can use mysql scheduler to run it each 5 seconds. You can find samples at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html

Never used it but I hope this would work:

```
CREATE EVENT myevent
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 5 SECOND
    DO
      CALL delete_rows_links();
```

Comment: i only replace delete_rows_links with this, but apparently doesn't work.
DELETE FROM `database_charts`.`activation_link_password_reset`  WHERE  TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, `time`, NOW()) < 1;

Comment: @user455318: "doesn't work" --- isn't an explanation. What mysql version do you use? What error did you get?

Comment: i cant enable the SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON; give me an error of connection

Comment: @user773961: uhm, php?!?!? perform **everything** directly in mysql console.

Comment: What mysql version do you use? scheduler is available only in mysql 5.1

Comment: ok. point of situation. the SHOW PROCESSLIST\G show the process event_scheduler, but any row is deleted in the interval of 5 seconds

Comment: oh ... 5.0.51a. probably is the problem

Comment: I think this should be `DO CALL delete_rows_links();`

Comment: [I have a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38029868/how-dichotomous-quantity-intervals-work-in-an-event). If you have some free time, please take a look at it.

Comment: Make sure to also turn on the mysql scheduler: `SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;`

Answer (score 16):

I used this query and it worked for me:

```
CREATE EVENT `exec`
  ON SCHEDULE EVERY 5 SECOND
  STARTS '2013-02-10 00:00:00'
  ENDS '2015-02-28 00:00:00'
  ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE
DO 
  call delete_rows_links();
```

Answer (score 11):

In order to create a cronjob, follow these steps:

1. run this command : SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
2. If ERROR 1229 (HY000): Variable 'event_scheduler' is a GLOBAL
   variable and should be set with SET GLOBAL:
    mportant

It is possible to set the Event Scheduler to DISABLED only at server startup. If event_scheduler is ON or OFF, you cannot set it to DISABLED at runtime. Also, if the Event Scheduler is set to DISABLED at startup, you cannot change the value of event_scheduler at runtime.

To disable the event scheduler, use one of the following two methods:

1. As a command-line option when starting the server:

   ```
   --event-scheduler=DISABLED
   ```
2. In the server configuration file (my.cnf, or my.ini on Windows systems):
   include the line where it will be read by the server (for example, in a [mysqld] section):

   ```
   event_scheduler=DISABLED
   ```

   Read MySQL [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events-configuration.html) for more information.

   ```
    DROP EVENT IF EXISTS EVENT_NAME;
     CREATE EVENT EVENT_NAME
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 10 SECOND/minute/hour
    DO
    CALL PROCEDURE_NAME();
   ```

Answer (score 4):

If you're open to out-of-the-DB solution: You could set up a cron job that runs a script that will itself call the procedure.

Comment: Cron cannot run command each 5 seconds. He is good with 6 hours interval though.

Comment: Yeah I replied with OP's comment in mind, I should have specified it!

Comment: Unfortunately, before MySQL 5.1 this seems to be the only option, as events were introduced with that version.