# How can I execute the program automatically when datetime column in mysql comes to current time?

Tags: mysql, datetime

I want to execute the program when datetime column set in mysql comes to current time. Is there a useful way to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "execute the program" ?

Comment: Concretely speaking, python script to update user data in mysql.

Answer (score 2):

use a cronjob for runnng the program on the desired time.
Write a program in php or any language , which deals with interaction with the database. then make that program file to run as a cronjob at specific time intervals

Comment: I see. Actually desired time is refreshed frequently. So I'm looking for more smart way other than cronjob.

Comment: you can add the code to update the desired time on that cronjob program. also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560639/how-to-schedule-a-stored-procedure-in-mysql

Comment: Cron is useful to run the script on the desired time, but this is out-of-DB-session. MySQL event can't handle the script other than sql. I want to use both of them(scripts and mysql), so is there any way to merge them?

Comment: You write a program in php or any language , which deals with interaction with the database. then make that program file to run as a cronjob at specific time intervals