# How is it possible to bind a function to mysql such that when a condition is met the function automatically triggers?

Tags: mysql

I want to bind functions using mysql such that when a condition is met at a later time, the function automatically triggers ..

table my_date contains column triggertime .triggertime stores the final a function need to be trigggered when it is greater than the current time. How is it possible too implement this?

Comment: Define a avent that checks the column content regularily.

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560639/how-to-schedule-a-stored-procedure-in-mysql and here (based on what juergen said) http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html