# Delete data from mysql innodb tables after one month is passed

Tags: mysql, cron

Currently i am using cron for this. I thought perhaps it is possible to implement some procedure that will remove all data from database that is older than one month, but i am not sure that this is the best way.

Problem is that we have many servers with many cron processes, that are controlled by very small amount of stuff, and we need to make it clear and easy-to-manage, that's why i don't want to have such cron process.

Data in table i want to delete - statistics, huge amount of this data is inserted every day, and if it will not be deleted - database will be unbeliaveable huge (about ~500M every day, for us it's quite big amount, 500M * 365 days is 182,5G per year)

Is it possible to delete data using some procedure in mysql (perhaps after new row is added) / and is that a good idea?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560639/how-to-schedule-a-stored-procedure-in-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're intending on moving away from cron jobs, you could always create an [event](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html) that runs at a scheduled frequency.

Whatever you do, it's a very bad idea to delete data every time a new row is added, as it'll slow down your insert and it's more likely to fragment your tables.

Comment: yup, u're right.. seems that cron is still best solution for this.. performance is more important for us there. thank you.