# How do i create a repetitive MySQL Event in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that needs to be updated every 5 days by members. The event scheduler is to set any stale row to zero, if the row's last update is older than 5 days.
My development environment is:

```
Windows 7, 32bit.
MySQL 5.5.39
PHP 5.4.45
```

My first query was:

```
$query = 'CREATE EVENT event_name
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 5 HOUR 
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE 
DO
UPDATE database_name.table_name SET table_column_name = 0 WHERE (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - last_update_date) > 5 DAY'
```

I ran the script in PHP but the browser simply stopped. Displaying 'Server not found'.

Then I tested it in phpMyAdmin. This time I get:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax. Check the mysql manual that corresponds to your mysql server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'DAY'.

I checked MySQL Reference Manual (for version 5.6, though). My query seems correct, unless I'm missing something. So I changed the query to:

```
CREATE EVENT event_name
STARTS '2015-11-01 00:00:00'
ENDS '2030-11-01 00:00:00'
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 5 HOUR 
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE 
DO
UPDATE database_name.table_name SET table_column_name = 0 WHERE (NOW() - last_update_date) > 5 DAY
```

Still got the same results. 
In reference to a related topic (([How to schedule a stored procedure in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560639/how-to-schedule-a-stored-procedure-in-mysql))), there's no `event_scheduler` in my php info.

Please help.

Comment: One issue might be that CURRENT_TIMESTAMP returns only time values and it seems last_update_date is datetime,nevermind DAY is unnecessary.YOu might want `TIMESTAMPDIFF` function

Comment: You're right, last_update_date is DATETIME.
Thanks. I'll look up how to apply the function to my query.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a problem with your the query you are trying to execute on the event. You could use DATE_SUB() assuming last_update_date is datetime.

```
UPDATE database_name.table_name SET table_column_name = 0 WHERE DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 DAY) < last_update_date
```

Comment: You're right to assume last_update_date is DATETIME. 'Cos it is. Thanks for an example  on how to adapt the query to DATE_SUB(). Tested it and it worked.