# How two-part-quantity intervals work in an EVENT?

Tags: mysql, sql

Based on the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-event.html), there is multiple kinds of interval quantity:

[image]

Ok I'm fine with single ones: `YEAR`, `MONTH`, `DAY`, `SECOND`, ...

But I cannot understand how duplex ones work: `YEAR_MONTH`, `DAY_HOUR`, `MINUTE_SECOND` ...

---

Please take a look at this *EVENT*:

```
CREATE EVENT myevent
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 5 SECOND
    DO
/* query here */
```

*EVENT* above will be executed every `5` second. That's pretty clear. But how following *EVENT* works?

```
CREATE EVENT myevent
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 5 MINUTE_SECOND
    DO
/* query here */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MINUTE_SECOND =>    'MINUTES:SECONDS'

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html

WHEN YOU USE MINUTES_SECONDS YOU HAVE TO GIVE IT IN ABOVE FORMAT

Comment: CREATE EVENT myevent ON SCHEDULE EVERY '1:5' MINUTE_SECOND DO SELECT NOW();
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.09 sec)

Comment: But what about `DAY_SECOND`? I hardly think it suppose to be like this `DAY:SECOND`

Comment: it is DAY_SECOND     => 'DAYS HOURS:MINUTES:SECONDS'